# Godot просит обновить openGL

Tags: opengl, godot

Вот такая проблема,видеокарта на ноутбуке intel (r) hd graphics family 3000 windows 7 x64
драйвера на видеокарте стоят последние, подскажите может кто знает как решить проблему? openGL я так понимаю должен быть установлен по умолчанию[image: Скрин]

Comment: Купите новый ноутбук

Comment: а другие врянты есть?)

Answer (score 1):

Этот GPU поддерживает только DirectX 10.1 и OpenGL 3.0. А Godot по-умолчанию использует OpenGL 3.3. Можно попробовать переключить видео на OpenGL 2.1 выставив [Project > Project Settings > Rendering > Quality > Driver](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-property-rendering-quality-driver-fallback-to-gles2) в значение GLES2.

Comment: спасибо, я уже сам додумался))